# How to change an FTP upload VBScript to SFTP

Tags: file-upload, vbscript, ftp, sftp

I  want to change this to the SFTP server. How should I update this following script?

```
'FTP Upload
'Upload a file/folder to an FTP server 

Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objFSO
Varnow = now
vardate = Day(varnow) & "-" & Month(varnow) & "-" & Year(varnow) & ".csv"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFile = "D:/file.csv"
strRename = "D:/file-" & vardate
If objFSO.FileExists(strFile) Then
    objFSO.MoveFile strFile, strRename
End If

'Path to file or folder to upload
path = strRename

FTPUpload(path)
```

```
Sub FTPUpload(path)

    On Error Resume Next

    'Copy Options: 16 = Yes to All
    Const copyType = 16

    'FTP Wait Time in ms
    waitTime = 8000

    FTPUser = "ftuser"
    FTPPass = "psw"
    FTPHost = "hostname"
    FTPDir = "/Dir"

    strFTP = "ftp://" & FTPUser & ":" & FTPPass & "@" & FTPHost & FTPDir
    Set objFTP = oShell.NameSpace(strFTP)

    'Upload single file      
    If objFSO.FileExists(path) Then
        Set objFile = objFSO.getFile(path)
        strParent = objFile.ParentFolder
        Set objFolder = oShell.NameSpace(strParent)

        Set objItem = objFolder.ParseName(objFile.Name)

        objFTP.CopyHere objItem,copyType
    End If

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Wscript.Echo "Error: " & Err.Description
    End If

    'Wait for upload
    WScript.Sleep waitTime
    If objFSO.FileExists(strRename) Then
        objFSO.MoveFile strRename, strFile
    End If
End Sub
```

So as you see I want to switch the FTP upload to SFTP upload (because the destination server have been changed to the SFTP protocol. What should be modified exactly in the this function `Sub FTPUpload(path)` to do so?
Have you any tips to do so?

Answer (score 2):

There's no support for SFTP in `FileSystemObject`, nor any other way in Windows.

You have to use a 3rd party SFTP command-line client or COM object.

So there's no easy way to change your existing script. You have to basically start from the scratch.

---

There are lot of existing questions on Stack Overflow for SFTP uploads with VBScript.

You can for example use [WinSCP SFTP client](https://winscp.net/). It has both [command-line scripting interface](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) and [COM object](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library).

- [Using WinSCP scripting in Windows Scripting host (JScript or VBScript)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation_advanced#wsh)
   Does not require any installation, but it's more difficult to use from VBS.
- [Using WinSCP .NET assembly/COIM library in Windows Scripting host (JScript or VBScript)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_com_wsh)
  Requires installation (registration), but it's easier to use from VBS.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*